# Problem running auto py to exe from terminal

Tags: python, pip, path, auto-py-to-exe

I've installed auto-py-to-exe with no problems, but when I try to run it from the command line, this appears:

```
"auto-py-to-exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

I've installed python with add to PATH enabled, but I still suspect that something is wrong with it.
How do I fix this?

Comment: When you ran `pip install auto-py-to-exe`, it should have printed a message about a path (ending in `Scripts`) not being in your `PATH`. Add it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bauto-py-to-exe%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command